# Linux sh -c output to /dev/null

Tags: linux, shell

If I run this command in a Linux shell:

`echo 'hello world' &> /dev/null`

I get no output, as expected. However, if I run:

`sh -c "echo 'hello world' &> /dev/null"`

It outputs `hello world`. Why is this? I thought that `sh -c` ran the given command inside a new shell; the given command should direct its output to `/dev/null`, leaving nothing to `stdout` for `sh -c` to return?

Comment: `&>` is a bash feature that only works in bash, so you'd have to use `bash -c` to get the effect you want. In `sh`, the line is interpreted as the two commands `echo 'hello world' &` and `> /dev/null`

Comment: Ah, got it. Is there a `sh` equivalent for it?

Comment: In `sh` you would use `> /dev/null 2>&1`